# Sphinx char_set resource?

Tags: char, sphinx

I need to have Sphinx index some characters that are apparently part of the internal char_set, notably "," and "&".

As far as I understand there is no way (?!) to simply add these as indexable chars, I need to

1. Make a char_set table in my index
2. Not only include the "," and "&" as indexable characters but now manually add the char_set Sphinx uses

This is a little frustrating as it seems one should be able to add back in chars without manually recreating the char_set used internally. However if that is the situation that is the situation, yet in the documentation

```
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html
```

I don't see or understand how I would manually specify a char_set table and exclude / index the two or three characters I want.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to duplicate the 'stock' `charset_table` before you can add to it.

At less than 100 characters, even if you typed it rather than copy/pasting, would still be les effort than typing this whole question!
(even less if use the the `english` shorthand)

Just copy what there and add your new chars to the end. If you don't know the unicode mapping, something like asciitable.com is useful at least for the chars in ASCII.

Comment: My config did not have a stock charset_table. I did some searching and found this: http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html, I notice btw they say one of the things it says is "A should be considered equal to a". Now if I want things like "Class A" and "Level B" and "Avenue A" I can must make those exceptions afterwards?

Comment: Sort of. Exceptions happen after charset_table processing, so cant be case sensitive (if made insensitive in charset_table), use the regexp_filter trick already shown. Also sounds like http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2014/11/26/sphinx-text-processing-pipeline/ might be useful reading.